# Net::SMPP in Perl, how to send acknowledgement to SMSC from my ESME

Tags: perl, sms, smpp

I am writing a Perl script that would act as a receiver & transmitter using Net::SMPP. When a mobile subscriber will send a message to a short code (say 123), it would reach to my SMPP account, and my SMPP application would read the message and reply with an acknowledgement to the user, some thing like "Thankyou for sending message".
I receive message sent by the user to my SMPP app totally fine. The problem is sending back an acknowledgement (delivery_sm_resp) to the SMSC so that it removes that message from the stream, so that next message sent by other user can be collected. I tried using the function but I cant figure out where to get the message_id from the message received from SMSC to my ESME.

My code is.

```
my $transmitter = Net::SMPP->new_transmitter($host,port=> $port,system_id => '123',password  => '',) or die;

$receiver = Net::SMPP->new_receiver($host,system_id => '123',password => '',port => $port,)
    or die "Can't create server: $!";

while (1) {
    warn "Waiting for PDU";
    $pdu = $receiver->read_pdu() or die "$$: PDU not read. Closing connection";
    print "Received #$pdu->{seq} $pdu->{cmd}:". Net::SMPP::pdu_tab->{$pdu->{cmd}}{cmd} ."\n";
    warn Dumper($pdu);

    print "\n\n ** Hello ** " . $pdu->{message_id} . "\n ** now printing ** " . $pdu->{sm_default_msg_id};
    $transmitter->deliver_sm_resp( message_id => $pdu->{sm_default_msg_id}, seq => $pdu->{seq});
    $resp_pdu = $transmitter->submit_sm(
        destination_addr => $pdu->{source_addr},
        short_message    => "you sent a message with text " . $pdu->{short_message}
    ) or die "Response indicated error: " . $resp_pdu->explain_status();

}
```

The display of message i receive from the SMSC to my ESME is as follows. Please help me locating the message_id from it, which can be used in acknowledging the SMSC, so that it removes that message from the stream, and next message sent by other user can be entertained. Otherwise i receive the same PDU 3 times and till that timeout the next message cant be entertained.

```
Waiting for PDU at s.pl line 23.
Received #2 5:deliver_sm
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'source_addr_ton' => 1,
             'known_pdu' => 1,
             'schedule_delivery_time' => '',
             'protocol_id' => 0,
             'status' => 0,
             'short_message' => 'A',
             'dest_addr_npi' => 0,
             'source_addr' => '44702601843',
             'validity_period' => '',
             'registered_delivery' => 0,
             'dest_addr_ton' => 0,
             'seq' => 2,
             'data_coding' => 1,
             'service_type' => '',
             'replace_if_present_flag' => 0,
             'cmd' => 5,
             'priority_flag' => 0,
             'data' => '44702601843420A',
             'destination_addr' => '420',
             'esm_class' => 0,
             'sm_default_msg_id' => 0,
             'source_addr_npi' => 0,
             'reserved' => undef
           }, 'Net::SMPP::PDU' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:
I was checking this out more and found out that for sending acknowledgement response from ESME --> SMSC the following command should be used in the code. I hope it helps someone, sometime. :)

```
$receiver->data_sm_resp(message_id => $pdu->{sm_default_msg_id}, seq => $pdu->{seq});
```

Answer (score 0):

Attached is the code which allowed me to receive sms

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# Copyright (c) 2001 SymLABS <symlabs@symlabs.com>, All Rights Reserved.
# See README for license. NO WARRANTY.
#
# 10.7.2001, Sampo Kellomaki <sampo@symlabs.com>
# $Id: esme-rec.pl,v 1.4 2002/02/11 16:43:47 sampo Exp $
#
# ESME in receiver role.
#
# Test Net::SMPP in SMSC role
#
# Usage: ./esme-rec.pl *version*
#    version can be 4 or 3             #4

use Net::SMPP;
use Data::Dumper;

$trace = 1;
$sysid = "username";
$pw = "password";
$host = 'ip address';
$port = port;
$facil = 0x00010003;
($vers) = @ARGV;
$vers = $vers == 4 ? 0x40 : 0x34;   #4
$if_vers = 0x00;

use constant reply_tab => {
    0x80000000 => { cmd => 'generic_nack', reply => undef, },
    0x00000001 => { cmd => 'bind_receiver',
            reply => sub { my ($me,$pdu) = @_;
                   $me->set_version(0x34);
                   $me->bind_receiver_resp(system_id => $sysid,
                               seq => $pdu->{seq});
                       }, },
    0x80000001 => { cmd => 'bind_receiver_resp', reply => undef, }, 
    0x00000002 => { cmd => 'bind_transmitter',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->set_version(0x34);
                   warn "Doing bind_tx_resp";
                   $me->bind_transmitter_resp(system_id => $sysid,
                               seq => $pdu->{seq});
                   }, },
    0x80000002 => { cmd => 'bind_transmitter_resp', reply => undef, }, 
    0x00000003 => { cmd => 'query_sm',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->query_sm_resp(message_id=>$pdu->{message_id},
                              final_date=>'010711135959000+',
                               seq => $pdu->{seq},
                              ) }, },
    0x80000003 => { cmd => 'query_sm_resp', reply => undef, },     
    0x00000004 => { cmd => 'submit_sm',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->submit_sm_resp(message_id=>'123456789',
                               seq => $pdu->{seq}) }, },
    0x80000004 => { cmd => 'submit_sm_resp', reply => undef, },   
    0x00000005 => { cmd => 'deliver_sm', reply => undef, },    # we originate this
    0x80000005 => { cmd => 'deliver_sm_resp', reply => undef, },  # *** need to handle this?
    0x00000006 => { cmd => 'unbind',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->unbind_resp(seq => $pdu->{seq});
                   warn "$$: Remote sent unbind. Dropping connection.";
                   exit;
                   }, },       
    0x80000006 => { cmd => 'unbind_resp',
            reply => sub { warn "$$: Remote replied to unbind. Dropping connection.";
                   exit;
                   }, },
    0x00000007 => { cmd => 'replace_sm',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->replace_sm_resp(seq => $pdu->{seq}) }, },
    0x80000007 => { cmd => 'replace_sm_resp', reply => undef, }, 
    0x00000008 => { cmd => 'cancel_sm', reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                           $me->cancel_resp(seq => $pdu->{seq}) }, },
    0x80000008 => { cmd => 'cancel_sm_resp', reply => undef, },  
    0x00000009 => { cmd => 'bind_transceiver',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->set_version(0x34);
                   $me->bind_transceiver_resp(system_id => $sysid,
                                  seq => $pdu->{seq});
                   }, },
    0x80000009 => { cmd => 'bind_transceiver_resp', reply => undef, }, 
    0x0000000b => { cmd => 'outbind',
            reply => sub {  my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                    $me->set_version(0x34);
                    $me->bind_receiver(system_id => $sysid,
                               password => $pw) }, },
    0x00000015 => { cmd => 'enquire_link',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->enquire_link_resp(seq => $pdu->{seq}) }, },      
    0x80000015 => { cmd => 'enquire_link_resp', reply => undef, }, 
    0x00000021 => { cmd => 'submit_multi',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->submit_multi_resp(message_id=>'123456789',
#                                 no_unsuccess=>0,
                              seq => $pdu->{seq} ) }, },
    0x80000021 => { cmd => 'submit_multi_resp', reply => undef, }, 
    0x00000102 => { cmd => 'alert_notification', reply => undef, },  # ***
    0x00000103 => { cmd => 'data_sm', reply => undef, },  # ***
    0x80000103 => { cmd => 'data_sm_resp', reply => undef, }, 

#4#cut

    # v4 codes

    0x80010000 => { cmd => 'generic_nack_v4', reply => undef, }, 
    0x00010001 => { cmd => 'bind_receiver_v4',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->set_version(0x40);
                   $me->bind_receiver_resp(system_id => $sysid,
                               facilities_mask => $facil,
                               seq => $pdu->{seq});
                   }, },
    0x80010001 => { cmd => 'bind_receiver_resp_v4', reply => undef, }, 
    0x00010002 => { cmd => 'bind_transmitter_v4',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->set_version(0x40);
                   $me->bind_transmitter_resp(system_id => $sysid,
                                  facilities_mask =>  $facil,
                                  seq => $pdu->{seq});
                   }, },
    0x80010002 => { cmd => 'bind_transmitter_resp_v4', reply => undef, }, 
    0x00010003 => { cmd => 'query_sm_v4',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->query_sm_resp(message_id=>$pdu->{message_id},
                              final_date=>'010711135959000+',
                              seq => $pdu->{seq}) }, },
    0x80010003 => { cmd => 'query_sm_resp_v4', reply => undef, },     
    0x00010004 => { cmd => 'submit_sm_v4',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->submit_sm_resp(message_id=>'123456789',
#                                  num_unsuccess=>0,
#                                  destination_addr=>$pdu->      {source_addr},
                               error_status_code => 0,
                               seq => $pdu->{seq} ) }, },
    0x80010004 => { cmd => 'submit_sm_resp_v4', reply => undef, },   
    0x00010005 => { cmd => 'deliver_sm_v4', reply => undef, },
    0x80010005 => { cmd => 'deliver_sm_resp_v4', reply => undef, },  # Need to handle this?
    0x00010006 => { cmd => 'unbind_v4',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->unbind_resp(seq => $pdu->{seq});
                   warn "$$: Remote sent unbind. Dropping connection.";
                   exit;
                   }, },       
    0x80010006 => { cmd => 'unbind_resp_v4',
            reply => sub { warn "$$: Remote replied to unbind. Dropping connection.";
                   exit;
                   }, },       
    0x00010007 => { cmd => 'replace_sm_v4',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->replace_sm_resp(seq => $pdu->{seq}) }, },
    0x80010007 => { cmd => 'replace_sm_resp_v4', reply => undef, }, 
    0x00010008 => { cmd => 'cancel_sm_v4',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->cancel_resp(seq => $pdu->{seq}) }, },      
    0x80010008 => { cmd => 'cancel_sm_resp_v4', reply => undef, },  
    0x00010009 => { cmd => 'delivery_receipt_v4',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->delivery_receipt_resp(seq => $pdu->{seq}) }, },
    0x80010009 => { cmd => 'delivery_receipt_resp_v4', reply => undef, },  
    0x0001000a => { cmd => 'enquire_link_v4',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->enquire_link_resp(seq => $pdu->{seq}) }, },
    0x8001000a => { cmd => 'enquire_link_resp_v4', reply => undef, },
    0x0001000b => { cmd => 'outbind_v4',
            reply => sub { my ($me, $pdu) = @_;
                   $me->set_version(0x34);
                   $me->bind_receiver(system_id => $sysid,
                              password => $pw,
                              facilities_mask => $facil,
                              seq => $pdu->{seq}) }, },
#4#end
};

($smpp, $resp) = Net::SMPP->new_transceiver($host,
                  smpp_version => $vers,
                  interface_version => $if_vers,
                  system_id => $sysid,
                  password => $pw,
                  addr_ton => 0x01,
                  addr_npi => 0x01,
                  source_addr_ton => 0x01,
                  source_addr_npi => 0x01,
                  dest_addr_ton => 0x01,
                  dest_addr_npi => 0x01,
                  system_type => '',
                  facilities_mask => $facil,
                  port => $port,
#               timeout => 7,
                  )
    or die "Can't create server: $!";

warn Dumper $resp;

print "#### Connected: ###### \n smpp:$smpp, \n resp:$resp";


while (1) {
 warn "Waiting for PDU";
 $pdu = $smpp->read_pdu() or { $bind_fail = "yes" };

Net::SMPP::Pdu_tab->{$pdu->{cmd}}{cmd} ."\n";

### read in data
 $short_message = $pdu->{short_message};
 $source_addr = $pdu->{source_addr};
 $seq = $pdu->{seq};

print "\n ===> Bind failed=$bind_fail \n";

########### if bind failed above - try to reconnect
 if ($bind_fail eq "yes"){
 print "\n Reconnecting \n";
 ($smpp, $resp) = Net::SMPP->new_transceiver($host,
 smpp_version => $vers,
 interface_version => $if_vers,
 system_id => $sysid,
 password => $pw,
 addr_ton => 0x00,
 addr_npi => 0x01,
 source_addr_ton => 0x0,
 source_addr_npi => 0x1,
 dest_addr_ton => 0x0,
 dest_addr_npi => 0x1,
 system_type => '',
 facilities_mask => $facil,
 port => $port,
 # timeout => 7,
 )
 or die "Can't create server: $!";
 sleep 2;
 }#fi bind_fail

warn Dumper($pdu) if $trace;
 $mh_msg_id = "$pdu->{seq}";

 if (defined reply_tab->{$pdu->{cmd}}) {
 $smpp->deliver_sm_resp(message_id => $mh_msg_id, seq => $mh_msg_id) or die; ### we use pdu->    {seq} as message_id, as we cannot find message_id, fix later

warn "Replied";

} else {
 warn "Don't know to reply to $pdu->{cmd}";
 sleep 1;
 }
 }


#EOF
```